# 3D- Model is not rendering in ARCore Augmented Faces in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, blender, arcore

I am following [ARCORE AUGMENTED FACES iOS](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-ios-sdk) SDK. In-build fox_face.scn is working fine for me.

Now we have created some 3d models in Blender & export them in both .dae OR .obj formats. From xcode I converted these models in scn but when i try to render my scn models, its not rendering on face.

Same scn model is working fine with [ARKIT](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/tracking_and_visualizing_faces) but not working with [ARCORE](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-ios-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

In case, your model has any animation, check if your 3D file follows the requirements from here: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/animation/obtaining-assets

Answer (score 0):

Rendering on iOS is done within ARKit scene, not ARCore. ARCore Face Augmentation is generating the 3D face assets which are delivered to SceneKit to render with each frame callback.

I'm not sure exactly why you said scn model is working fine with ARKit, but not AR Core?

I have been successful in exporting from Blender to .dae, and then converting to SceneKit file in xcode.

Having said that, I have been unsuccessful in cleanly exporting the default fox face and bones (and my geometry) from blender directly into Xcode to create what the demo has from default.

Instead I have had to copy/paste 3D geometry content from the imported/converted scene from blender into the original fox_face scene that comes with the project, ensuring all axis are correct.

In order to correctly position the asset relative to the original fox face I had to create some code to move the model around in the world.

I hope that helps.

But I would be very interested if you find a way to export cleanly from blender (including default face or fox ears etc) directly in as a whole scene, including your new geometry.